# DB links use good or bad

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a situation where I have to rout a xml feed into a single schema and sync the data with multiple schemas.

ex. SCHEMA_1@DB1, SCHEMA_2@DB2

File will send to SCHEMA_1 and manipulated data needs to be inserted, update or select from the second one also.

**Meanwhile I am using DB links to fulfill this requirement and curious to know that I am going with good approach.**

Note: I have to perform this task with the help of procedure only that why I am using DB links.

Please suggest if there is any performance issues with this approach or any dynamic error situation can occur, other drawbacks if any.

Comment: ..No `Bulk` on a DB-link..

Comment: @kara can you please clear the picture in term of "Bulk" are you referencing large dataset or something else.

Comment: `forall` and `bulk collect` won't work on a db-link. If you don't need them i don't see a problem in using db-links.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can't be answered easily. I would try to stick on the commication-strategy you're using in your project/other projects.

If your using webservices to communicate, you could also use it for your problem. But if you don't have any interfaces yet, db-links are the easiest way to move the data. This way you don't need to code anything (sounds like you already got some stored procedures).

But be aware:

`forall` and `bulk collect` won't work on a db-link. If you don't need them i don't see a problem in using db-links.

And think about adding hints for bigger selects:

```
SELECT /*+DRIVING_SITE(b)*/
      *
  FROM localTable a, otherTable@otherDb b
 WHERE a.id = b.id
   AND a.Name like '%x%'
   AND b.Name like '%y%';
```

This way you tell your db, that the statement should be calculated on "otherDb". This is useful if you got a very small local table and a bigger one in another db. You always should filter the big one first and then start to join other tables.

Anyway: Every situation has it's own requirements.

Comment: thanks for your contribution @kara. and what about the performance and load on db's as compare to other modes to db-links.

Comment: If you only want to move data from one db to another, a db-link is most time the fastest solution. If you have code in this movement, you should consider other technologies to align to your dev-strategy. In example: You work with 100 `C#`-Developers. Then it would not be a good idea to start coding plsql.